# How to execute and run millions of unit tests quickly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

How do you execute millions of unit test quickly, meaning 20 to 30 minutes?

Here is the scenario:

- You are releasing certain hardware and you have, let's say, 2000 unit tests.
- You are releasing new hardware and you have additional 1000 tests for that.

Each new hardware will include tests, but also you have to run and execute every previous one, and the number gets bigger as does execution time.

During development, this is solved by categorizing, using the `TestCategory` attribute and running only what you need to.

The CI, however, must run every single test. As the number increases, executing time is slower and sometimes times out. The `.testrunconfig` is already set for `parallelTestCount` execution, but over time this does not solve the issue permanently.

How would you solve this?

Comment: Did someone actually sit down and write 2000 relevant, interesting, separate tests, or are we talking automatically generated tests? The latter might benefit from executing whole groups of tests by reading structured data, instead of tiny little methods representing individual pinpricks. You can at least independently optimize that; optimizing MSTest would be quite a bit harder. (MSTest also supports data-driven unit tests, which are a possible alternative, but I don't think those are actually faster to execute, just more convenient.)

Comment: We are talking about manual written tests. So far 4380. They are not generated. As far as optimization, each test lasts milliseconds, not a single one over 1 second

Comment: If every test took (say) 10 ms, and you have 4380 tests, then even with a sequential run it should take no more than a minute to run all tests. If you find the CI server takes (much) longer than that, it's worth looking into where the overhead is coming from (file access from logging the results?). I haven't done any profiling of MSTest myself, but I imagine it might not be particularly optimized since it's not usually asked to run a huge amount of tests. You could also consider alternatives like NUnit, or even a custom runner (enumerating tests by reflection isn't hard).

Comment: Could you provide more data about what actuall takes so long?  Test execution is fast, as you say.  What about build times?  Are you linking all dependencies into your tests?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like with each update on Visual Studio 2017, execution time changes. We currently have over 6000 tests, of which 15 to 20% are unit tests, and the rest are integration tests.

The bottleneck seemed to be the CI server itself, running on a single machine. 70% to 80% of the tests are asynchronous, and analysis showed that there are no blocking I/O operations. Besides IO, we do not use databases, caching so there is that.

Now, we are in the process of migrating to Jenkins and using its Parallel Test Executor Plugin to parallelize the tests across multiple nodes instead of a single machine. Initial testing showed that timing for executing 6000+ tests varies from 10 to 15 minutes versus the old CI which took 2 hours or stopped sometimes.